# How to navigate between panes in vim and tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm using tmux and vim and I want to navigate between panes easily. I want to use Ctrl+h/j/k/l to switch between panes. I have this in my .vimrc :

```
Bundle 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j
nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>k
nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>h
nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l
```

And I have this in my .tmux.conf

```
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
```

It works to switch between tmux's panels but it does not works inside vim. What can I do to make it working inside vim?

Comment: without prefix using `c-h/j/k/l` isn't a good idea. if you use emacs keybind cmd line editing, you lost `backspace, remove current till end, clear screen` features.

Comment: Don't try to make it work. That windows in windows in windows mess is not worth the hassle and using the same keybinding in tmux and vim is quite possibly the worst fix. Use vim key bindings in vim and tmux key binding in tmux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly, I make it work by upgrading tmux to the latest version.